# fixed width text file from two tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need pointed to the correct direction.  I need to create a fixed width file from Access.  The data will be coming from 2 tables (employer and employee).  The text file must display the employer record, then the next records will contain employee data.   The resulting file layout with then be used to upload into a separate system.

For example:

**Employer Table**

> ```
> RecordID - 2 char - always 01
> EmployerNumber - 6 char
> EmployerName - 25 char
> ReportID (pk) - Not included on text file, only used to relate employer with employee
> ```

**Employee Table**

> ```
> RecordID - 2 char - always 02
> EmployeeNumber - 4 char
> EmployeeName - 25 char
> ReportID (fk) - Not included on text file, only used to relate employee with employer
> ```

**Resulting text file:**

```
01012345PENGUINS
028686CROSBY
027777MALKIN
026666LEMIEUX
01012345ACME INC
021122BUGS BUNNY
021133DAFFY DUCK
029872ROAD RUNNER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that [ReportID] is integer, so the sample data looks like this for [Employer] ...

```
ReportID  EmployerNumber  EmployerName  RecordID
--------  --------------  ------------  --------
       1  012345          PENGUINS      01      
       2  012345          ACME INC      01
```

... and this for [Employee] ...

```
ReportID  EmployeeNumber  EmployeeName  RecordID
--------  --------------  ------------  --------
       1  8686            CROSBY        02      
       1  7777            MALKIN        02      
       1  6666            LEMIEUX       02      
       2  1122            BUGS BUNNY    02      
       2  1133            DAFFY DUCK    02      
       2  9872            ROAD RUNNER   02
```

the query

```sql
    SELECT 
        RecordID & EmployerNumber & EmployerName AS RowData,
        CDbl(ReportID) AS RowSort
    FROM Employer
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        RecordID & EmployeeNumber & EmployeeName AS RowData,
        CDbl(ReportID) + Val(EmployeeNumber) / 10000 AS RowSort
    FROM Employee
```

returns

```
RowData            RowSort
-----------------  -------
01012345PENGUINS         1
01012345ACME INC         2
028686CROSBY        1.8686
027777MALKIN        1.7777
026666LEMIEUX       1.6666
021122BUGS BUNNY    2.1122
021133DAFFY DUCK    2.1133
029872ROAD RUNNER   2.9872
```

so the query

```sql
SELECT RowData
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                RecordID & EmployerNumber & EmployerName AS RowData,
                CDbl(ReportID) AS RowSort
            FROM Employer
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                RecordID & EmployeeNumber & EmployeeName AS RowData,
                CDbl(ReportID) + Val(EmployeeNumber) / 10000 AS RowSort
            FROM Employee
    )
ORDER BY RowSort
```

returns

```
RowData          
-----------------
01012345PENGUINS 
026666LEMIEUX    
027777MALKIN     
028686CROSBY     
01012345ACME INC 
021122BUGS BUNNY 
021133DAFFY DUCK 
029872ROAD RUNNER
```

Just save that last query in Access and then export it as text.

Comment: realized it must be an SQL limitation on number of fields.  When i eliminate employer fields.  it works.  But need all 111 fields to complete the text file.  would a different database program be better to use?

Comment: @exceldude2001 If you run just the `SELECT ... FROM Employer` subquery with all 111 fields does that work? If so, then another option might be to use some VBA code and a temporary table instead of a UNION query.

Comment: I discovered access limit is 100 fields per SELECT statement.  As a workaround, I thought about split the employer table (staging table?), then somehow concatenate two select statements?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a little complicated for a beginner but it has 2 parts:

1. You need to join the 2 tables.  You should google for 'SQL Inner Joins' for a few examples.
2. You need to export the data in the format you want.  You can do this with using the `Left()` function.

Assuming your tables are called Employee and Employer, consider this SQL statement:

```
Select
ER.RecordID & 
left(ER.EmployerNumber & "      ",6) & 
left(ER.EmployerName & "                         ",25) & 
EE.RecordID & 
Left(EE.EmployeeNumber & "    ",4) & 
Left(EE.EmployeeName & "                         ",25) as SingleCol
From Employee EE
Join Employer ER on EE.ReportID=ER.ReportID
```

This query joins the 2 tables (see the `Join` at the bottom) and displays first the 3 fields from your Employer table followed by the 3 fields from the Employee table.  The `Left()` statement with all the spaces pads the field with spaces.  This query will return exactly 1 long text field.